# Does a linear expression exist for these ILP variables?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I am formulating an integer linear program.

Suppose I have a set of binary variables $X_{i,j,k}$ that is $1$ if subject $i \in I$ is taught by lecturer $j \in J$ during timeslot $k \in K$, or $0$ otherwise.

This means, without additional refinement, $X_{i,j,k}$ will represent $|I|\times|J|\times|K|$ variables.

Now, suppose instead I have two set of variables $Y_{i,j}$ and $Z_{i,k}$ that is $1$ if subject $i \in I$ is taught by lecturer $j \in J$, or $0$ otherwise; and $1$ if subject $i \in I$ is run at timeslot $k \in K$, or $0$ otherwise, respectively.

If this works, these two sets represent $|I| \times (|J| + |K|)$ variables, which should be quite a lot less.

There is technically enough information here to work out at what timeslots $k \in K$ lecturer $j \in J$ is teaching, as you can "backtrack" from $Z$ to $Y$.

What I haven't been able to do, despite my best efforts, is to come up with a single, *linear* expression of $X_{i,j,k}$ in terms of $Y_{i,j}$ and $Z_{i,k}$. I'm beginning to doubt such an expression exists.

Answer (score 0):

If subject $i$ is taught by lecturer $j$ and subject $i$ is run at timeslot $k$ ($Y_{i,j}=Z_{i,k}=1$), there are still two possibilities:

- either subject $i$ is taught by lecturer $j$ at timeslot $k$, which means $X_{i,j,k}=1$,
- or it is taught only taught by different lecturers at that time slot, which means $X_{i,j,k}=0$.

Therefore, without additional information, you cannot express $X_{i,j,k}$ as a function of $Y_{i,j}$ and $Z_{i,k}$ only.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your second possibility at all?

Comment: @Ozzah suppose $Y_{i,j}=1$, which means lecturer $j$ teaches subject $i$. Given $Z_{i,k}=1$, there is no way of knowing whether teacher $j$ is actually the one teaching subject $i$ at timeslot $k$, or somebody else. These two cases are possible, and result in a different $X_{i,j,k}$.

Comment: If Y_i,j = 1 and Z_i,k = 1, then X_i,j,k must necessarily also be 1, by definition. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Ozzah Using the definition you gave us, $Y_{i,j}=1$ means lecturer $j$ teaches subject $i$ _at some time_. $Z_{i,k}=1$ means subject $i$ is taught at time slot $k$ by _some lecturer_. Am I correct? Unless we are talking about a trivial case (only one lecturer or only one time slot), then $X_{i,j,k}$ can be anything.

Comment: @Ozzah For instance, if lecturer $j_1$ teaches subject $i_1$ at time slot $j_2$, and lecturer $j_2$ teaches subject $i_1$ at time slot $k_1$, then we have $Y_{i_1,j_1}=Z_{i_1,k_1}=1$, but $X_{i_1,j_1,k_1}$ is not necessarily 1.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot to mention that. One subject is run at most once, and a subject is taught by exactly one lecturer if we choose to run it. In other words, you can be sure that Y and Z can be mapped to X, however I just need to know if it can be done explicitly, in a single, linear expression.

Comment: Oh, in that case you can disregard everything I just said. The function you are looking for exists, and it is simply
$$
    X_{i,j,k}=Y_{i,j}\wedge Z_{i,k}
$$
To convince yourself of that fact, you can write a truth table, there are only 4 cases to consider.

Comment: Ok, well using "standard" operators that can be used in ILP, that's $X_{i,j,k}=Y_{i,j} \times Z_{i,k}$. This is obvious, however it's certainly non-linear.